# what triggers Elastic Beanstalk to pull in an updated Docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerhub

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application running and configured to serve a Docker container ("generic Docker" configuration) and linked to a private image on Docker Hub.

How can I prompt the Elastic Beanstalk application to download the latest version of the docker hub image after pushing up a new version with `docker push`?

Do I need to "restart the app server," "rebuild the environment," something else, or is "supposed" to pull it in automatically? Not seeing this addressed in the docs.

** EDIT **
To be clear, `eb deploy` does NOT pull in an updated Docker image, but it does push up the files from your application directory to your ec2 instances.

So, at the end of the day I'm probably not going to use `docker push` for deployments, but just to keep the image up to date in the case that you actually need to make ENVIRONMENT configuration changes, not code changes, or when bringing on a new developer, you can use `docker pull`.

Currently `eb deploy my-environment-name` is working great for Docker based Elastic Beanstalk deployments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to run command line: eb deploy. Here is a nice tutorial http://victorlin.me/posts/2014/11/26/running-docker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk.

Comment: The tutorial refers to Dockerrun.aws.json v1. Do you know how to make it pull the image with v2?